# Generic Method to find a Cache object of collection and update an item where ID matches

Tags: c#, generics, caching, in-memory

In my ASP.NET MVC application, I am using InMemoryCache and wrote a generic method for Setting a CachedObject

```
  public T GetOrSet<T>(string cacheKey, Func<T> getItemCallback) where T : class
        {
            if (MemoryCache.Default.Get(cacheKey) is T item) return item;
            item = getItemCallback();
            MemoryCache.Default.Add(cacheKey, item, DateTime.Now.AddHours(8));
            return item;
        }
```

And I call it as following

```
_cacheService.GetOrSet("KeyName"),
                () => LoadDataFromDB(params));
```

Now I want to write a similar generic method to update cached object

```
_cacheService.MergeItem<Customer>("KeyName", newCustomer, newCustomer.Id);
```

And that implementation should be something like

```
public void MergeItem<TSource>(string cacheKey, TSource newOrUpdateItem, object idValue)
    {
        if (!(MemoryCache.Default.Get(cacheKey) is TSource item)) return;

        var sourceList = item as List<TSource>;
        if (sourceList != null)
        {
            var key = typeof(TSource).GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(p =>
                p.CustomAttributes.Any(attr => attr.AttributeType == typeof(KeyAttribute)));

            var firstOrDefault = sourceList.FirstOrDefault(x => x[key] == idValue);
            if (firstOrDefault != null)
            {
                sourceList.Remove(firstOrDefault);
            }
            sourceList.Add(newOrUpdateItem);
        }
        MemoryCache.Default.Set(cacheKey, sourceList, DateTime.Now.AddHours(8));
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Sooo... what's the problem?

Comment: I am stuck with the implementation of void MergeItem<T>(string cacheKey, T, object id) not able to complete it

Comment: Still pretty vague there - Are you getting some sort of build error, or run-time error, or something else?

Comment: What's the point of id argument to merge item? You already have cache key.

Comment: Lets say, I have 100k Customers in my Memory Cache and I updated or added new Customer, I want to update this one record in the memory and update the cache, instead of clearing he cache object fully and reloading all 100k customers from DB again.

Comment: @MattSpinks update my question with screenshot, I need help with FirstOrDefault of Generic Type and casting the comparison fields

Comment: This implementation is asking for troubles. Instead, store each item in its own cache entry (so customer with id 1 with cache key "Customer_1" for example). No need to cache list of items.

Comment: @Evk Wouldn't that be too much to have 100k keys for 100k customers and if I have a page where I have to show grid of all customers, how do I reach that data? Again read from all cache keys begins with Customer and create a list from it?

Comment: No, 100K cache items is not a problem (actually there will be much less, because you only cache customers that are actually retrieved, not all 100K at once). But this is for query by id, not for lists. For lists you need to cache each page individually. If you can afford caching whole table at once - it might be better to just use something like ConcurrentDictionary instead of MemoryCache.

Comment: @Evk can you please point me to any example implementation of ConcurrentDictionary where I can store large list of Customers, Audit info (user session activity) for reports and other?

Comment: For access by id, any example will do (just use `ConcurrentDictionary<long, Customer>` where long is type of customer id). It has similar methods (`GetOrAdd`, `AddOrUpdate` and so on). For lists that is more compilcated, because `ConcurrentDictionary` is unordered. Caching lists (with filters, sorts, paging) in general is quite complicated. If you don't need super fast perfomance - you can in theory use your implementation, but you absolutely need to add locks, because now it's not thread safe.